# div doesn't center on pageX and pageY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem centering a div element which has an id of zoom-lens. zoom-lens is position:absolute and I can't center the div with this code

code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mediabox = function(options){  
        
        var config = $.extend(config, options);
        
        $(this).bind('init', function(){            
            $(config.data).each(function(index, element){
                // preload images //
                $('#zoom-lens').hide();

                if($(this)[0] != true) {                    
                    new Image().src = config.path + $(this)[1];                 
                }               
            }) 
        }).trigger('init')
        .find('#zoom-box').mousemove(function(e) {
            var index = $(this).find('div:visible').not('#zoom-lens').index();
            // enable zoom-lens
                
            if(config.data[index][0] == false){
                                    // here is where i'm having the problems                    
                var left = e.pageX - ($('#zoom-lens').width() / 2);
                var top = e.pageY - ($('#zoom-lens').height() / 2);
                $('#zoom-lens').css({'left':left + 'px', 'top':top + 'px'}).show();
                
                /*$('#zoom-lens').draggable({
                    'containment': '#zoom-box',
                    drag: function (event, ui) {

                    }
               })*/
                $('#cords').text(e.pageX);
            }
        }).end()
        .find('.small-thumb').mouseover(function(e) {
            //alert($(this).data('id'));            
            $('#zoom-box div').hide();          
            $('#zoom-box div:eq(' + $(this).data('id') + ')').show();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            if(config.data[id][0] == false){            
                $('#zoom-box div:eq(0)').html('');
            }else{
                $('#zoom-box div:eq(0)').html(config.data[id][1]);  
            }
        });;
    }   
})(jQuery);
```

relevant code:

```
var left = e.pageX - ($('#zoom-lens').width() / 2);
var top = e.pageY - ($('#zoom-lens').height() / 2);
$('#zoom-lens').css({'left':left + 'px', 'top':top + 'px'}).show();
```

i've tried using marginLeft and that gives me the same result. Here is a link to my page which displays a list of images and a video, select an image and mouseover the large image and it will show the zoom-lens but it won't align centered. Here is the  [link](http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/view/apple-iPad-mini-MD531LL-A-16gb-wifi-white.php)

so what I want is the zoom-lens to be exactly in the center of the mouse cursor vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Why we have to go to some external page (that BTW one day will be off, so not useful to anyone) and sneak for code? Please post all the relevant things here. And explain what you mean by "center" cause it's not clear from your Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your container is in a relative position, you need to add his offset in your calcul.

```
var left = e.pageX - ($('#zoom-lens').width() / 2) - $('#zoom-box').offset().left;
var top = e.pageY - ($('#zoom-lens').height() / 2) - $('#zoom-box').offset().top;
```

Comment: Thanks for you're effort you almost had the code right except it was  ($('#zoom-lens').width() / 2) - $('#zoom-box').offset().left; A minus instead of plus